# Good Probability Practice Problems

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm looking for a good probability textbook with lots of worked out examples and problems to prepare for my course's final exam. I'm in an introductory probability class in college, and we've covered basic probability, combinatorics, and discrete and random variables. We're using Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition, by Bertsekas and Tsitisklis, but I've gone through a lot of problems in that already. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find a set of probability problems?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894579/where-can-i-find-a-set-of-probability-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with Sheldon Ross' *A First Course in Probability*. It has tons of worked problems, many (sometimes over a hundred) exercises per chapter, and solutions to those exercises in the back of the book (or online).