# Where can I find a set of probability problems?

Tags: probability, reference-request, permutations, combinations, bayes-theorem

Is there a database of solved probability problems available?

I am currently studying probability (and statistics) and, while I think I have a decent grasp of permutations, combinations, conditional probabilities, and Bayes' theorem, I would love to work through a few hundred problems to check both my solutions and my reasoning.

Comment: there are plenty on this site: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schaum's outlines have plenty of problems and solutions. The [probability/statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007179557X) one has 760 solved problems, whilst the [probability/random variables/random processes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071822984) has 405.

Alternatively try [Khan Academy probability and statistics](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability). They have plenty of online exercises.

But I'd also go back to my comment, viz. that you can learn a lot on this website. There are loads of probability questions, and giving them a go and getting the right answer in a similar time to others is quite a challenge. And even if you do get it right, you'll often find (as I did recently [answering this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893342/how-to-calculate-the-probability-of-rolling-6-at-least-5-times-in-a-row-out-of/893468#893468)) that others have taken a different approach that you can learn from.

Comment: Thank you, TooTone!  I had completely forgotten about Schaum's and I never realized that Khan Academy offered problem sets.